# dnsmasq: failed to start DNS caching server

Tags: linux, centos, sandbox, dnsmasq

Im trying to sandbox my dnsmasq on a CentOS9 machine. I have this exact config running on a CentOS8 (with all the sandbox parameters uncommented), but the upgrade to CentOS9 seems to break it. I have a dnscrypt-proxy running aswell on port 2053.

When I have dnsmasq not sandboxed, everything starts and runs fine. But as soon as I create a simple sandbox for dnsmasq, the dnsmasq startup fails, complaining that the DNS server cant start.

**Journalctl output**
[image: journactl output]

**/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

[image: dnsmasq.conf]

**/etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service.d/01-sandboxing.conf**
[image: 01-sandboxing.conf]

**systemctl status dnsmasq output**
[image: systemctl status dnsmasq output]

I have also seen a "couldnt bind port 53: Permissions denied" error. When checking whether anything is listening on port 53, nothing appears. So I guss this must be caused by the sandbox but Im not sure what exactly.

I tried commenting out lines of the sandbox but it seems to fail no matter how much I comment out.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I think.
By removing the user and group line from the sandboxing.conf, dnsmasq properly starts up. I do not think we changed anything about the dnsmasq user, so I assume that dnsmasq first starts as root, then tries to change its user but fails because it already **is** the user *dnsmasq*. Or because dnsmasq first does setup as root, and fails because it already got assigned to the dnsmasq user. Either one.

I cant be 100% sure, but thats my theory.

I'm gonna look into potential security concerns by letting dnsmasq change its user by itself, and generally if I can find a way for it to work even with the user parameter, but for now I will just leave these two lines out